# Website that collect RESTful requests

Tags: rest

I used to use a service (website) that gave me a temporary bin that I could use for testing RESTful requests. It was really useful as I could debug applications really quickly if they weren't working the way I expected.

I have since lost the website - and don't remember the name.

Does anyone know of a service that does this?

Comment: would a browser plugin like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/restclient/ for firefox or https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo for chrome suffice?

Comment: @RussCam Thanks, but i'm behind a deep firewall, so it's hard to get any inbound connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

For future readers, check out http://requestb.in/